# struts2 json result type for ajaxfile upload

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, struts2

I have code as below, but still i am getting json result as download file. I couldn't find where is the mistake.

i am using 
ajaxfileupload.js
jquery-1.7.2.min.js
struts2-core-2.3.4.jar
struts2-json-plugin-2.3.4.jar

my Struts.xml

```
<action name="hierarchyruleValidate" method="validateRulesFile"
            class="com.cotyww.bru.web.action.master.HierarchyUpdateAction">
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            </result>
            <result name="error" type="json">
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

My Ajax script:

```
function validateFile(Url, resultID, buttonId)
{
    $('#validatesuccessId').attr('style','display:none');
    $("#loading")
        .ajaxStart(function(){
            $(this).show();
        })
        .ajaxComplete(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $.ajaxFileUpload({
                url:Url,//
                secureuri:false,//false
                fileElementId:'fileToUpload',//id  <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
                dataType: 'json',// json
                success: function (data, status)  //
                {
                    alert(data.successMessage);//jsonmessage,messagestruts2
                    if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                    {
                        if(data.error != '')
                        {
                            alert(data.error);
                        }else
                        {
                            alert(data.message);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function (data, status, e)
                {
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
        );
        return false;

}
```

My Action class

```
    public String validateFile() throws ApplicationException {


//******* Application logic with uploaded file******

            this
                                            .setSuccessMessage("Are you sure you want to upload the file");
                    this.getHttpResponse().setContentType("text/html");

                    return Action.SUCCESS;
                }
```

Comment: Try `application/json` as your content type

Comment: in validateFile()  mehod or in struts.xml?